# Codecept run provides different result on travis than in local

Tags: symfony, travis-ci, codeception

I am running some codeception tests. They are successful when I launch them locally.
[image: Screenshot of codeception local tests]

For integration tests, I add them on Travis, but a lot of test failed!
[image]

So, I add this command on `.travis.yml`: `cat tests/_output/*`

The result explain why tests are failing. Here is the output of a page on travis environment:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    </head>
    <body>
         [THE FORM]
    </body>
</html>
```

As you can see, my base template is not loaded on travis environment.

Here is a truncate part of the same login page locally generated:

```
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
            <link href="/css/f5f986f_app_1.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen" />
        <link href="/css/f5f986f_bootstrap.min_2.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen" />
        <link href="/css/f5f986f_bootstrap-theme.min_3.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen" />
        <link href="/css/f5f986f_font-awesome.min_4.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen" />

    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

                <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/52ec12c_jquery.min_1.js"></script>

    <title>G-Equip&nbsp;&bull; Log in</title>
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="/favicon.ico" />        </head>

<body>
   [....]
   [THE FORM]
   [....]
</body>
</html>
```

Here is my test:

```
class AuthCest
{
    public function _before(FunctionalTester $I)
    {
        $I->amOnPage('/login');
        //Menu verification
        $I->seeInTitle('Log in');
    }
}
```

So, in local the page is well loaded with its template. But on Travis, I don't have my full template, I don't have the title tag! So, this test failed on: `$I->seeInTitle('Log in')`

Codeception throw this failure:

> Fail  Tag element with `<title>` was not found.

**Why the views are different on travis environment?**

Here is a simplified version of my .travis.yml file:

```yml
# Project language
language: php

# Allows use container-based infrastructure
sudo: false

# Start mysql service
services:
    - mysql

# Cache composer packages so "composer install" is faster
cache:
  directories:
    - $HOME/.composer/cache/files

php:
  # aliased to a recent 7.1.x version
  - 7.1


# Define an environment variable
env:
  - SYMFONY_VERSION="3.3.*" DB=mysql

# Update composer
before-install:
  - composer self-update

before_script:
  - cp app/config/parameters.yml.travis app/config/parameters.yml
  - composer install
  - mysql -e 'create database symfony;'
  - php bin/console doctrine:migrations:migrate  --no-interaction
  # loading data for phpunit and codeconcept tests
  - php bin/console doctrine:fixtures:load --fixtures ./src/AppBundle/DataFixtures -n --env=test

script:
  # Server must be started for codeconcept tests.
  - php bin/console server:start
  - php vendor/bin/codecept run
  - php bin/console server:stop
  - cat tests/_output/*
```

**Something is certainly misconfigured, do you have an idea?**

Comment: It seems you have cache busting code prepended to your CSS and JavaScript files locally - does that get done by some build step? Is that build step running properly on Travis?

Also, are your Codeception functional tests run using an actual browser, or just PHPBrowser at the moment?

Comment: Thanks for your help @ocean, But no, CSS and JS come from assetic. In my travis, they have been installed and dumped. CSS and JS are present (and work well) in `HomeCest.php`. Here is a link to the travis result : https://travis-ci.org/Alexandre-T/gequip/jobs/262382481 .

This is functional tests, not acceptance tests. So they do not use an actual browser.